# Protecting Unity game for Game Guardian

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to protect my game from Game Guardian.

But he has random package name. How I can detect him? After install Game Guardian install new app with random generated package name `com.IakamIska` and I can't detect him with the process name. I want to protect my game.

I used `try-catch` him using process name. But he generated random name.

Comment: As long as you run code on the clients computer you are at the mercy of the client. Whatever preventions you add, the client can simply remove if motivated and knowledgeable enough. The only real method to avoid this is to run the game logic on a server. This is important for competitive multiplayer games. But who cares if someone cheats in a  single player game?